# Do table relationships have to be established in both SQL backend and VB.Net frontend?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I'm getting ready to build my first SQL database using SSMS for the backend and Visual Studio to build the VB.NET user form(s).

**Do I have to establish the table relationships in Visual Studio? Or are the relationships still intact (or recognized) from SQL when I link Visual Studio to my SQL Dataset?**

Sorry if this question seems silly, I'm use to Access but I want to grow :).

Thank you,

- Justin

Comment: What do you mean relationship? Are you talking about the relationship between tables? If so, this is all maintained on the server. VB doesn't need to know anything about them.

Comment: Your question is vague and needs to be clarified significantly.  The answer could be yes or no, depending on exactly what you want to do with the data.  For instance, a typed `DataSet` will contain `DataTables` and `DataRelations` between them, allowing you to navigate data and add new related data.  The application absolutely has to understand the relationships in order to propagate foreign keys.

Comment: Sorry, yes, table relationships. You guys answered my question perfectly. Thank you!